# On OpenGL, is there any way to tell glTexSubImage2d not to overwrite transparent pixels?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

On OpenGL, I'm using `glTexSubImage2d` to overwrite specific parts of a 2D texture with rectangular sprites. Those sprites have, though, some transparent pixels (`0x00000000`) that I want to be ignored - that is, I don't want those pixels to overwrite whatever is on their positions on the target texture. Is there any way to tell OpenGL not to overwrite those pixels?

This must be compatible with OpenGL versions as low as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `glTexSubImage2d` will copy the data to the texture directly no matter what the source or the target is.

I can only suggest you to create another texture with the data you are trying to push using `glTexSubImage2d` and then draw this texture to your target texture. This will lead to a pretty standard drawing pipeline so you can do whatever you want using blend functions or shaders.